# Prevent snap auto-refresh for a specific package

Tags: ubuntu, snap

The snap update of the openjdk will break some of my applications so I would like to keep it to specific version. I know how I can set a specific version, but not how to keep it there.

Some AI suggested
`snap set openjdk refresh.metered=hold`, which looks exactly what I want but I get the error:

```
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Run configure hook of "openjdk" snap (snap "openjdk" has no "configure" hook)
```

Any idea how to proceed?

System: Ubuntu 22.04.02

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
snap refresh --hold=forever openjdk
```

Comment: https://snapcraft.io/docs/keeping-snaps-up-to-date